# Under what conditions children of a node in Bayesian network are independent if the probability of the parent is unknown?

Tags: probability, bayesian, bayesian-network

> Given the following graph:
>
> $$\lower{4ex}X\lower{2ex}\swarrow Y\lower{2ex}\searrow\lower{4ex}Z$$
>
> define the probabilities such that Z and X are independent while the value of Y is unknown and prove that Z and X are indeed independent.

I know that if X and Z are independent then $P(X,Z)=P(X)\cdot P(Z)$. Also a node is conditionally independent of its non-descendants given its parents. But I'm not sure how to proceed with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know that if X and Z are independent then $P(X,Z)=P(X)⋅P(Z)$. Also a node is conditionally independent of its non-descendants given its parents. But I'm not sure how to proceed with this.

Yes, indeed, the outline is :

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X,Z) & =\sum_Y \mathsf P(X,Y,Z)
\\[0ex]&~~\vdots
\\[1ex]&=\sum_Y \mathsf P(X)\,\mathsf P(Y\mid X,Z)\,\mathsf P(Z)
\\[1ex]&= \mathsf P(X)\,\mathsf P(Z)\sum_Y\mathsf P(Y\mid X,Z)
\\[1ex]&= \mathsf P(X)\,\mathsf P(Z)
\end{align}$$

You just need to justify that step.

Comment: can you please explain 1) why $\mathsf P(X,Z)=\sum_y \mathsf P(X,Y,Z)$? 2) why $\sum_y \mathsf P(X,Y,Z)= \sum_y \mathsf P(X) \mathsf P(Y|X,Z) \mathsf P(Z)$?

Comment: I can only think of chain rule: $P(X,Y,Z)=P(X|Y=T, Z)\cdot P(Y=T|Z) \cdot P(Z)$ but it doesn't explain your transitions.

Comment: You have to explain the *factorisation* using the DAG. @Yos

Comment: According to factorization: $P(X,Z)=\sum_{Y\in \{T,F\}}P(X,Z|Y)P(Y)$. Because we're interested in the case when $X,Z$ are independent then: $\sum_{Y\in \{T,F\}}P(X,Z|Y)P(Y)=\sum_{Y\in \{T,F\}}P(X|Y)P(Z|Y)P(Y)$. I don't understand how you get your transitions.